# Excel userform - setting focus of textbox on exit if condition not met

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel userform with textboxes to put various information (first name, last name, gender, height, etc.). For some of the textboxes, I want to apply a sort of validation.

For the gender field, for example, the only values that are acceptable are "M" or "F." I have this bit of code. If you type "M" or "F" and tab out of the field, it goes to the next textbox. But if it's anything else, the MsgBox will pop up like it should, but after you click OK, the focus is not set to the textbox.

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't this work?

```
Private Sub txtGender_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If txtGender.Value <> "M" And txtGender.Value <> "F" Then
MsgBox ("Invalid gender.")
txtGender.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When you have a finite set of possible values, UI conventions call for using either radio buttons (for 2-3 values) or a combobox (for more). Using an unrestricted textbox is just wrong for this. Also this is 2017, consider which option a hermaphrodite or transgender person is going to select. That said, the parentheses around the `MsgBox` argument(s) should be dropped. All they're doing is making VBA evaluate the string literal as a value expression, force-passing it `ByVal` to the `MsgBox` function, and potentially causing compile errors when you start adding more parameters, e.g. title/icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the `Exit` event within your `If` statement.

```
Private Sub txtGender_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If txtGender.Value <> "M" And txtGender.Value <> "F" Then
  MsgBox ("Invalid gender.")
  Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this, and it's not setting the focus to the txtGender field.

Comment: The code above prevents the textbox from losing focus on my system. https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/enter-exit-events states "To prevent the control from losing focus, assign True to the Cancel argument of the Exit event."